# VB.NET Setting width for multiple columns in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 13 columns, 10 of which have width = 58, is there any syntax to assign multiple columns?

I know this dose not work but is there any thing like,

dgv1.Columns[(0),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)].Width = 58

Comment: Not randomly like that, no.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I think I know what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working.

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12})
For Each col As Integer In list
    dgv1.Columns(col).Width = 58
Next

dgv1.Columns(1).Width = 75
dgv1.Columns(2).Width = 50
dgv1.Columns(3).Width = 200
```